# how do handle if data in each table increases within same index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

index created for multiple table from a database. Over a period of time record of a couple of table increased and a couple of table has millions of record. but initially it has hundreds of record. So if count of records are increased, how do make better performance.
1) do we need to move the table from old index to newly creating index
or
2) increase the nodes and shards of existing index, thus make better performance.

so i am looking better solution and pls let me know, if my requirement is not clear.

Could anybody answer please.

Comment: could you suggest on this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you should consider using timeseries-based indices, so
you would create an index for every day or month (or whatever time period you
wanted) and then you could use a tool like
[curator](https://github.com/elastic/curator) to manage them. This way you have
more flexibility with what to do with older indices, like closing them, deleting
them, or force-merging them using the optimize API.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have performance issues, it's going to be harder. Since the number of shards is fixed at index creation time, you will have to reindex the data to a new index with more shards.

If you have tables that grow indefinitely (e.g. logs) plan ahead with time-based indexes. If your data is not time-based you can do the same trick. Use templates to automatically create indexes and aliases so you can query them as it would be one index.

There is no golden rule here, but once you know that for example how your index scales for your usecase for 1M records you can do some automatic indexing by id from your primary storage (db). All you have to do is, when indexing pick the right index to write to (since you can't use alias for indexing), querying is transparent through alias. This is a minor change for most apps.